# How to improve Elasticsearch query with ML/NLP?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am currently using a fairly standard query with my Elasticsearch search. The only addition I am using is the metaphone analyzer. I wanted to know whether there are any in-built NLP or ML add-ons for elasticsearch. I am slightly out of my depth, but if anyone can point me to some resources, it would be of great help!

Comment: What are you trying to acheive with NLP/ML and if you could better explain the use case it would be helpful.

Comment: A couple of things. For example, a user selects a paragraph, can I use elasticsearch to find similar paragraphs with the similar semantic meaning. Second, how to build a auto suggest system based on user data? Can we build smarter search? For example, if the user searches for 'legal cases related to transfer of property'. This could be searches in a couple of ways. Transfer could be sale, conveyance. Property could be land, building, apartment. Also, words like 'to' or 'the' can be placed at different positions or even may not exist. Rhank you for looking into this@alexgids

Comment: Any leads @alexgids?

Comment: I think your question is much too broad my friend, and I don't think you will get the kind of answers you want. 

Most of the elasticsearch analyzers involve NLP pre-processing, allowing for stop words, stemming ngramming etc. "NLP" means what to you? You can find this in their documentation. Elasticsearch also provides a non-free Machine Learning plugin for time series data. This means its good at identifying anomalies in log data. On top of this stackoverflow isn't the place to ask for software library recommendations. Good luck on your hunt!

Comment: @IanGabes I apologise for such an open-ended question. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You already use some of NLP by using standard mapping of Elasticsearch. **Tokenization, stemming & stop words**, all of those are language specific and use NLP for parsing.

[Built-in analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/analysis-analyzers.html)

When it comes to search engine building, what you probably have in mind is 'better similarity' and more precise retrieval.

**ES uses TF-IDF** model for similarity by default (which is an NLP/ML method in itself)

[Modules Similarity](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html)

You could definitely throw NN at it, but there isn't any specific guide for doing so. I can recommend book by *Tommaso Teofili, "Deep Learning for Search"* which actually describes all that you could do with ML in context of building search engine.

Comment: Yeah. Was wondering how to build and integrate an NN with it. I'll check out the book.

Comment: This book mainly talks in terms of Lucene, anything for Elasticsearch specifically?

Comment: ES is based on Lucene actually. It shouldn't be too hard to transfer a lot from this book into ES, especially that ES is designed for ease of such implementations. Remember what you want to use ML for (similarity) in your context. There will be no difference between ES/Lucene or Solr in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [LearnToRank](https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank) plugin - Its very interesting if you are about 'relevancy' .

Also this [plugin](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp) , to enrich document during ingest using OpenNLP

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the use of enriching documents while ingesting?

Comment: Also, @Nirmal, can you please answer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376466/boolean-query-with-elasticsearch?noredirect=1#comment106823520_60376466